# Remove standard TouchUpInside animation

Tags: swift, uibutton

I am trying to customise the look and feel of a button when you press it in an iOS application using Swift. I am currently adding targets to it, with both TouchDown and TouchUpInside, but the standard "darkening" of the button label still remains. How do remove this button-label animation?

Answer (score 0):

Make the button a Custom button instead of a System button. That way, just about everything about its look is left up to you.

Comment: How can I go about doing this with the button? How do I access the associated animation?

Comment: If you don't understand the answer why did you accept it?

Comment: Because it sounds very likely that it will work. I just lack the sufficient knowledge to get it to work.